# how to print the same string separated by space n times

Tags: java, string, split

I want to make Santa Claus say "Ho" a total of "n" times, where I specify "n".
I know how to print it n times, but I don't know how to properly insert a separator between the "Ho"s, such that the result looks like:  "Ho Ho Ho"

My attempt at coding this up is given below:

```
public class Main
{
    public static String repeat(String str, int times) {
        return new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String Ho="Ho";
        int n=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(repeat(Ho, n)+"!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a for loop. Try again, I'll bet that you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ho = "Ho";
        int n = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(repeat(ho, n) + "!");
    }

    public static String repeat(String str, int times) {
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0 ; i<times ; i++){
            builder.append(str).append(" ");
        }
        return builder.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Since Java 11

We can use [`String#repeat​(int count)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)). With it your code can look like

```
int n = 3;
System.out.println("Ho" + " Ho".repeat(n-1) + "!");
//output: Ho Ho Ho!
```

#### Since Java 8

We can use [StringJoiner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) with space as delimiter.

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
String str = "Ho";
int n = 3;
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    sj.add(str);
}
String text = sj.toString();
System.out.println(text); //Ho Ho Ho
```

You can also use [StringJoiner(delimiter, prefix, suffix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html#StringJoiner-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) to automatically add `!` at the end of joined strings (as suffix);

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ","","!");
```

Comment: +1 I was not aware of this new Java 8 feature! Thank you for bringing it to my attention; I can finally do away with my `Strings.repeat` utility function.

Comment: @varzeak No problem. You may be also interested in `String.join` methods, or if you would like to use `stream()` you can also use `someStream.collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter))` :)